# Easy Way to Generate Chromatic Pitch Shifts for Many Audio Samples

Tags: software, pitch

I have a couple of audio samples (mp3, whatever, the format doesn't matter too much) that I'm trying to pitch shift chromatically while retaining the length of the sample. There's a super easy way to do this in Audacity, but I'm trying to generate 4 octaves chromatically for about 4 sound samples, and I'm not a fan of busywork - does anyone know of some easy way to generate chromatic pitch shifts of an audio sample without having to click a lot? Thanks!

Comment: As well as Sox, another option is rubberband (http://rubberbandaudio.com/). If you click on the *Developers!... Find out more here" link, there's a command line version you can download - I've used it for exactly what you describe.

Comment: I do this in native instruments time and pitch machine. Logic pro x also works well for this.

Comment: The format actually DOES matter.  Give a pitch-shift algorithm as much information as possible to work with.  Degrading the audio to a compressed format such as MP3 will increase the chance of nasty artefacts.  And don't stretch too far.  There's a reason why quality sample sets use a new source sample every few notes.

Comment: I was pitch-shifting with wav and it worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an Ableton user, you can convert your .mp3 files to wav then you can drag the audio file to Ableton. It gives you an option to pitch shift as well as wrap (it changes the pitch without changing tempo).
Another method is to change the pitch and adjust the tempo.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across SoX thanks to a friend, which is a command line utility that'll take care of this issue - more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/292833/how-to-change-audio-frequency/292834#292834)